# How to sort a list using a Boolean compare function using the Python sorted function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a binary function which returns a Boolean indicating whether the first argument is strictly less than the second argument.
Can I use the `sorted(my_list, key=functools.cmp_to_key(boolean_cmp))` or some variant thereof to sort this list?  Or do I need to refactor the `boolean_cmp` function so that it returns a positive, negative, or zero integer?

Do I really need to distinguish between the *greater-than* case and the *equal-to* case?

The `boolean_cmp` function is written as a several methods spread out over the program.  Refactoring them would be possible, but seems like more work than is necessary.

I've done a bit of experimentation and it *looks like* converting `False` to `0` and `True` to `-1` causes `sorted` to sort correctly.  But my experiment is only anecdotal.

BTW, I was reading [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) and it took me a long time to figure out that the underlying compare function needed an integer return value rather than a Boolean.   In my opinion, it would have been nice if that had been clearer. [grumble]

Comment: Rather than refactor it (since you use it elsewhere) wrap it in a lambda or proper function that returns what you want to return.

Comment: @JonSG, is it sufficient to convert False to 0 and True to -1, or do I need to distinguish between the == case and the > case?   Because if I need to distinguish all three cases, I cannot do this with a simple wrapper function

Comment: How about `lambda a, b : 1 if boolean_cmp(a, b) else -1 if boolean_cmp(b, a) else 0`?

Comment: Though I suspect `lambda a, b : 1 if boolean_cmp(a, b) else -1`  might be sufficient

Comment: @JonSG I suggest posting that as an answer, since I don't think there will be any better answer than that to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than refactor a method you already have in use, I recommend that you wrap a lambda around it that will try to return the -1, 0, 1 that functools.cmp_to_key() is hoping for.

Maybe something like:

```
lambda a, b : 1 if boolean_cmp(a, b) else -1 if boolean_cmp(b, a) else 0
```